# Static Synchronized Method to Access Static Field

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Hi I have a Utilities class.  It is a helper class with all static helper methods.
There is a static field within this class.

This class will never be instantiated.  It is only used as a helper via the static methods.

Even though this class will never be instantiated, I still think for thread safety sake, the static method should be synchronized while accessing the static field.  Am I correct?

```
public class Utils
{
    private static Map<String, String> messagesMap; 

    public static synchronized String getMessage(String key)
    {
        if(messageMap == null) {
            messageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            messageMap.put("john", "hello");
            messageMap.put("mary", "hi");
            // actual population of this map comes from a property file.
        }
        return messageMap(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in this method?

Comment: Please don't change your code to such an extent that the existing answers become invalid. Ask a new question instead of changing the existing one.

Comment: You need to put the whole class source that interacts with the messgesMap object. Does it get modified other places? Does anyones else inserts/removes elements from it? Are you passing a reference of this map to any other place? It really depends on the rest of the code in the class. If there is any other way of writing to the messageMap then it is not thread-safe. However, you can still do some improvements by using other implementations of Map. Consider using ConcurrentHashMap so that you don't have to lock the whole class and implementation is thread-safe from itself.

Answer (score 3):

I really suggest you initialize the static field at declaration (and mark it `final` if it's constant) and remove the synchronization from your method. Something like

```
private static final String message = "Hello"; // <-- needs a semi-colon.
public static String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
```

Remember, Java `String` is immutable.

For a `Map` I would suggest you use a `static` initialization block (and remove the synchronization and name your variables consistently). Like,

```
private static Map<String, String> messageMap = new HashMap<>();
static {
    messageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    messageMap.put("john", "hello");
    messageMap.put("mary", "hi");
    // actual population of this map comes from a property file.
}

public static String getMessage(String key) {
    return messageMap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: He doesn't have to use synchronization right?. His code (without synchronization) will always return `"Hello"` for any thread. And now he has changed his question *completely*

Comment: @Elliot Frisch, thanks for the tips on String.  I have updated my sample code to better describe what I am doing.

Comment: @user2712937 That's really different code, but my advice is substantially the same if edited to apply to `Map` instead of `String`. I've updated my answer, but I suggest you provide **real** code when you ask your question next time.

Comment: @user2712937 -  Also, if you are  *modifying your map* or *generating it in getMessage()*, you will have to synchronize on the method.

Comment: @TheLostMind Actually if the `Map` is to be modified, it would be better to synchronize on the `messageMap` instance; but there's a reason to prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer` and I think we all know what that is...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, noted about the real code, sorry.  Yes, the map is being set in a private static method, which is invoked inside the getMessage() method when the map is null.  My main concern is that by removing the synchronized keyword from the getMessage() method, there are chances the check on whether the map is null is dirty

Comment: @user2712937 A static initialization block takes care of that, and then you don't have to check whether the map is null. I see no advantage to lazy-loading here, but if you must lazy-load use a `synchronized` block.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks.  May I ask when is the static block invoked?  Is it the first time any static helper methods within this class are invoked?  or is it when the map is accessed the first time?

Comment: @user2712937 [JLS-8.7. Static Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) says (in part) *A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized ([§12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2))*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks!  If I do want it to be lazy loaded will it make any difference (performance wise) if I use a synchronized method or an AtomicReference<> field?  Excuse me as this could be another SO question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Right.. It would be better to *synchronize* on the map, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow access to and modifications of the static shared state from the multiple threads, the yes, you should use syncronization of some sort. Using synchronized keyword is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a private constructor to your class if you really do want that it shouldn't be instantiated.

Now, If the data fields are only for reference purpose and would never be changed then you just mark them final and the String will do the rest as it is [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Otherwise, you do need to synchronize the methods or code blocks, just make sure that synchronization should be done both at the time of access and modification and using the same lock.